# Variables always printing the previous values in React even after using set function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, callback

```
/import React from 'react';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ImageX from './images/X_image';
import ImageO from './images/O_image';

const PositionedComponent = ({ x, y, playersMove, handlePlayersTurn}) => 
{
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
    const [isPlayed, setIsPlayed] = useState(false);
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    
    const componentStyle = {
      width: '200px',  // Adjust the width as needed
      height: '200px', // Adjust the height as needed
      backgroundColor: isHovered ? 'lightblue' : 'blue',
      position: 'absolute',
      left: x,   // Position the component horizontally based on x prop
      top: y,    // Position the component vertically based on y prop
      cursor: 'pointer',
      transition: 'background-color 0.3s ease',
    };

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        setIsHovered(true);
    };
    
    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        setIsHovered(false);
    };

    const handleMouseClick = () =>
    {
        if(playersMove)
        {
          
          const imageToload = <ImageX x={x} y={y}/>
          setImage(imageToload)
        }
        else
        {
          const imageToload = <ImageO x={x} y={y}/>
          setImage(imageToload)
        }
        setIsPlayed(true);
        handlePlayersTurn();
    }
    return <div> 
        
        {isPlayed ?  
        (
          <>{image}</>
        )
        :
        (
            <div style={componentStyle}    
                onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} 
                onClick={handleMouseClick}
            ></div>
        )}
      </div>
  };


function TicTacToeGrid()
{
  // Your tic-tac-toe logic goes here
  const [playersMove, setPlayersMove] = useState(true);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState('');
  const [currPosition, setCurrPosition] = useState(false)
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(Array(9).fill('_'));

  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log("Player", symbol, "moved at", currPosition);
  }, [symbol]);


  const handlePlayersTurn = (position) =>
  {
    
    if(playersMove)
    {
      setSymbol('X')
    }
    else
    {
      setSymbol('O')
    }
    setPlayersMove(!playersMove)    
    setCurrPosition(position)
    console.log("Player", symbol, "moved at ", currPosition);  
  };
    
  const positon1 = <PositionedComponent x="0px" y = "0px"  playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() => handlePlayersTurn(1)}/>
  const positon2 =  <PositionedComponent x="210px" y = "0px" playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(2)}/>
  const positon6 =  <PositionedComponent x="420px" y = "0px"   playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(3)}/>
  const positon3 =  <PositionedComponent x="0px" y = "210px"   playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(4)}/>
  const positon4 =  <PositionedComponent x="210px" y = "210px"  playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(5)}/>
  const positon7 =  <PositionedComponent x="420px" y = "210px" playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(6)}/>
  const positon5 =  <PositionedComponent x="0px" y = "420px" playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(7)}/>
  const positon9 =  <PositionedComponent x="210px" y = "420px"  playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(8)}/>
  const positon8 =  <PositionedComponent x="420px" y = "420px" playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(9)}/>
 

  return (
      <div style={bigSquareStyle}> 
          <div style={topRow}>  </div>
          <div style={bottomRow}>  </div>
          <div style={rightCol}>  </div>
          <div style={leftCol}>  </div>
          {positon1}
          {positon2}
          {positon3}
          {positon4}
          {positon5}
          {positon6}
          {positon7}
          {positon8}
          {positon9}
         </div>
  );
}


const bigSquareStyle = {
    width: '620px',
    height: '620px', 
    backgroundColor: 'grey', 
    position: 'absolute',
  };

const topRow = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '10px', 
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    top: '200px',
    position: 'absolute'
};

const bottomRow = {
    width: '100%', 
    height: '10px', 
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    top: '410px',
    position: 'absolute'
};

const rightCol = {
    width: '10px', 
    height: '100%', 
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    right: '200px',
    position: 'absolute'
};

const leftCol = {
    width: '10px', 
    height: '100%', 
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    left: '200px',
    position: 'absolute'
}
export default TicTacToeGrid;
```

I'm currently learning React and the idea is to build a tic-tac-toe game. The structure has one parent component, the board. I have 9 child components each being a section of the board where you click to place your next move. I'm having this issue where in the handlePlayersTurn, the printed values are always the previous values. For example, if I click on any of the 1st components it will print undefined and false where I thought it would print the position and true(since it's the X's 1st move). From there it's always the previous move values getting printed.

I've tried using useEffect but doesn't seem to have any effect on fixing the issue I'm facing. I'm also not sure how to handle async functions like setPlayersMove() and setCurrPosition(). I've tried using fetch but that didn't help either. I'm stuck on trying to understand the async part of React. Any help/guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it did, thank you! I really just had to understand how useEffect works.